# how about allow the user login at the sametime?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, login-control

In my appliation,all pages are protected,so they must login to visit the pages.

And the admin of the system can add users.

Now some people told me that I have to prevent people login at the sametime using the same account.

That's to say if there is a user named "John" logined to the system,so other people cannot login with "John" again event he know the password.

Also,if one user find that someone have logined use the account he wanted,he can make the former user offline. If so I have to judge if the current user have been offed ornot in each page. This is not a work can be done easily.

I wonder if this is necessary?

Since I found so many websites nowdays do not limit this,for exmaple,you can use the same account login your gmail/stackoverflow/yahoo and ect in different machine at the same time.

So Any one can give me a suggestion?

---

**Update:**

Now,we use the asp.net's form authenciation,(we do not use the membership yet). And in the t_user table in the databse,we have a column named "isOnline" and "last_login_time".

When user login,we set the "isOnline" to 1,and store the login time.

When another user try to login again,we check the "isOnline" and the time:

```
if("isOnline"==1 && DateTime.now-LastLogiTIme <40min) // where the 40 min is the form authenaication timeout.
  thisAccountHasLogined=true;
```

But suppose a user logined yet,then he clean the browser cookie,then if he refresh the page,he will be redirected to the login page,but not he can never login again before the form authentication time out because the "isOnline" in the db is 1 and the time span from his login to now does not large than the form timeout.

I am confused.

Comment: why dont you check this condition on your every click and time to be 2 or 3 min, during every click it will be updated again and again

Comment: every click? I am sorry but I am not exactly sure your meaning.

Comment: have you seen some website where if you are inactive for some time , your session automatically expire, but if you are active your session is maintained

Comment: You could try adding some code into your Session_OnEnd which will perform a cleanup. However, in the scenario above (user explictly closes and clears cache) it will not change anything. In the above scenario, there is little you can do as there is no interaction with your server until it times out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some scenarios, I could understand not having multiple logins, but in reality, I have never had to implement it.

Unfortunately, I do not believe there is a standard mechanism for determining if a user is already logged in and this would need to be done by additional logic. In our application, we use a database for storing session information and using this, it would be a simple process to see if a session already exists within this for the user and not allow login if so.

**Update**

I was interested in this myself and found this;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipusercollection.aspx

and this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx

Using those, it may be possible to get this information with the `.IsOnline()` However, this does make the assumption you are using standard asp.net membership

Answer (score 0):

the table where you store user name and password add a column status
when a user attempt to login update status to "Online" when logout update status "Logout"
During login check status, if status is online , terminate process. This may be an approch to implement this, hope it will help you